# Where to find "adb" version 1.0.32 to install on Ubuntu?

Tags: adb, linux, twrp, side-loading

My laptop has Ubuntu 14.04 as OS. I installed latest version of "android-adb-tools" available in "Synaptic Package Manager". After installation, `adb` command `--help` says that `adb`'s version is **1.0.31**.

I used `adb sideload` to install a new ROM on my Samsung device (with TWRP version 2.8.4.0 as recovery), but command returns `error: protocol fault (no status)` and TWRP says that I have to use `adb` with version **1.0.32** or higher! Where i could find "android-adb-tools" package with `adb` version of 1.0.32 or higher?

Answer (score 7):

Download and untar

https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz

After this, just copy the extracted executable "adb" over old one in /usr/bin.

Comment: This works but not the best solution, hopefully an updated repo shows up somewhere...

Comment: It's better **not** to muddle with your repo-installed files in `/usr/bin`.  Just put the file somewhere new.  Make a `/bin` folder in your home directory.  Add it to your path if you want this version of adb to be chosen automatically.

Comment: @TobyJ: that would be nice, but as of now, no more recent package shows up at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=android-tools-adb

Answer (score 3):

You should download [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) and use it to install the Android SDK Tools, which includes `adb` and `fastboot`.

Comment: For more info, see: http://askubuntu.com/a/602141

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall old adb.
Get this,

https://packages.debian.org/sid/android-tools-adb

Install android-tools-adb and its dependencies manually from the above link, (sudo dpkg -i xxxxxxx.deb)

This will install adb with version 1.0.32 .
Hope this helps.

Comment: But I have latest version of  `android-tools-adb` : `4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23` and `adb version` results in `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31`

Comment: android-tools-adb 4.2.2xxxxx package consists of adb with version 1.0.31. You have to download and install android-tools-adb 5.1.1xxx along with its dependencies manually from the above [link](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/android-tools-adb/download) that I have provided. Then you will be having adb version 1.0.32 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to install a recovery that doesn't require the new version of adb.  I install CWM and was able to get around it this way.

Answer (score 0):

[If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?pkg=tools):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Then install adb and fastboot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Comment: For 64-bit Lubuntu, the command you provided to install the 32-bit libraries failed, but I found that you can download a 64-bit version of the platform tools (which includes adb and fastboot) here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#download.