# Attempting to update ADB from 1.0.31 to 1.0.32

Tags: adb, linux

I'm trying to update Android debugging software from version 1.0.31 to 1.0.32 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have consulted an earlier Stack Exchange post on the same topic [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97327/where-to-find-adb-version-1-0-32-to-install-on-ubuntu) but it has not helped.

I've been successful at this once before by following some well-written instructions posted [here](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb#h3-update-to-adb-1-0-32).  I'm including the relevant excerpt below:

```
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
wget -O - https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - adb
sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to replicate my earlier success.  After running the above commands, it appears that adb is not recognized as an updated version (ie, 1.0.32).  Instead, running the command below...

```
adb version
```

..provides a response that adb cannot be found.

I can easily revert to 1.0.31 by removing and then reinstalling adb tools:

```
sudo apt-get remove android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

But my goal is to update to adb 1.0.32.  An inspection of the archive showed me that it contains two files:

```
adb (library)
perfhost (executable)
```

I don't know what to make of these files.  My expectation would be that "adb" should be an executable.  I've tried executing "perfhost" but without any success.  At this point, I'm not quite sure how to continue troubleshooting this.  Perhaps the downloaded archive has changed since the above instructions were posted?  Perhaps I do not understand the purpose of the "adb" and "perfhost" files?  I'd appreciate help locating the updated version of ADB which, as others have noted still needs to be updated in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but incase someone else runs into the issue down the road and stumbles upon this question.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Adding more information on how this commands helps solve the problem would be useful

Answer (score 0):

My guess at your problem: the versions you have downloaded are 32-bit, and you have a 64-bit OS. The error message when trying to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit OS which does not have compat. libraries installed is very bad. It's "No such file or directory".